# No back button on Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox

I'm making a web based system, and I dont want the users to be able to view the source code, or go back

to hide the source code I changed the addressbar using this script

```
<script>
var stateObj = { foo: 'bar' };
history.pushState(stateObj, 'page 2', 'sistema');
</script>
```

And to disable back button I used this script

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward();
function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
```

modifying my body

```
<BODY onload="noBack();"
onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
</body>
```

They work separately fine, but when I put them together, the user is able to go back

Any ideas how to solve this?

Meanwhile I disabled the back button on the Browser, but this doesnt work for al computers

setting

about:config

```
pref browser.sessionhistory.max_entries to 0
```

setting this from a javascript will also solve my problem

tx in advance...

Comment: If I had to visit a site which could disable my back button with JavaScript, I'd immediately switch to Lynx...

Comment: I was in a chat the other day and someone said you could convert the encoding using an converter so it will make it hard to a particular audience to read.

Comment: Breaking the back button is EVIL. Don't be evil. There are few better ways to make someone frustrated and drive them away from your site forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide the source code. Period.

Person just has to use firebug (for example).

They may even be using a proxy.

Anyway why waste time to prevent them doing so?

PS: Javascript will not let you mess with the persons computer. Javascript lives in a sandbox

Comment: The thing is that they are my computers, and they will use them on my place, the sourcecode contains the passwords so I want to make it difficult for them to do it

Comment: @Bojack WHAT?!?!!?11@sd@!?!?!!?!?!?!!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm making a web based system, and I dont want the users to be able to view the source code, or go back

You can't and honestly you should stop trying. Only way to do it (as I'm thinking about it) is to build your website with flash.
But as I said you shouldn't try to do it. There are plenty of ways to see source code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is really not possible and if you find a way there will always be a floor in it. Developers look at other peoples website to see how they can implement a certain feature on their website and vice versa. Trying to do this will waste your time as like many other people who have tried this before and failed. Sorry.

Comment: ok ok thank you, I dont want to publish the website, I just want to leave it locally for instore use, because of the compatibility with Phones and OS... but thanks